# ROC curve not looking right

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, roc

I have plotted ROC curves, using ROCR package, for a 2 class problem. According to my understanding, the curves should look like step changing plots at least for smaller datasets. My input is in fact small but the curves I get are essentially straight line looking. Is it because PROC fits a line through the curve or is it something else that I am missing?

Input is here [click me](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9ivg9kzlu1758w/sensor6data_f21_s5_with2Labels.csv?dl=0) and the code is as follows with the ROC part at the end. Appreciate your help!

```
library("caret")
library("ROCR")
sensor6data_s10_2class <- read.csv("/home/sensei/clustering/sensor6data_f21_s10_with2Labels.csv")
sensor6data_s10_2class <- within(sensor6data_s10_2class, Class <- as.factor(Class))
sensor6data_s10_2class$Class2 <- relevel(sensor6data_s10_2class$Class,ref="1")

set.seed("4321")
inTrain_s10_2class <- createDataPartition(y = sensor6data_s10_2class$Class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training_s10_2class <- sensor6data_s10_2class[inTrain_s10_2class,]
testing_s10_2class <- sensor6data_s10_2class[-inTrain_s10_2class,]
y_s10 <- testing_s10_2class[,22]

ctrl_s10_2class <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 10 , savePredictions = TRUE)
model_train_multinom_s10_2class <- train(Class2 ~ ZCR + Energy + SpectralC + SpectralS + SpectralE + SpectralF + SpectralR + MFCC1 + MFCC2 + MFCC3 + MFCC4 + MFCC5 + MFCC6 + MFCC7 + MFCC8 + MFCC9 + MFCC10 + MFCC11 + MFCC12 + MFCC13, data = training_s10_2class, method="multinom", trControl = ctrl_s10_2class)
pred_multinom_s10_2class = predict(model_train_multinom_s10_2class, newdata=testing_s10_2class)

pred2_s10 <- prediction(as.numeric(as.character(pred_multinom_s10_2class)), as.numeric(as.character(y_s10)))
perf2_s10 <- performance(pred2_s10, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(perf2_s10,col='magenta',lwd=3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should predict the class probabilities instead of the class labels. Try this:

```
pred_multinom_s10_2class = predict(model_train_multinom_s10_2class, newdata=testing_s10_2class, type='prob')

pred2_s10 <- prediction(pred_multinom_s10_2class[,1], as.numeric(as.character(y_s10)))
perf2_s10 <- performance(pred2_s10, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(perf2_s10,col='magenta',lwd=3)
```

[image]

Comment: That's true, I totally forgot. Thanks for your help.